# TestNg DataProvider annotation can we return Object[][][]. 3 dimensional array instead of 2?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

In `Selenium TestNG`, `dataProvider` annotation can we return 3 dimensional Object array?

```
@DataProvider(name="")

public Object[][][] data() {

}
```

Comment: `The data provider supports injection too. TestNG will use the test context for the injection. The Data Provider method can return one of the following types:` take a look here https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you need to return 3d because you need to provide arrays to your test method. Like this:

[image]

Thus you can prepare the following data provider:

```java
@DataProvider(name = "3d")
Object[][] getData(){
    return new Object[][]{
            {new String[]{"one", "two"}, new String[]{"three", "four"}},
            {new String[]{"five", "six"}, new String[]{"seven", "eight"}}
    };
}
```

And use it in your test:

```java
@Test(dataProvider = "3d")
public void test3DDataProvider(String[] one, String[] two){
    System.out.print(Arrays.asList(one));
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(two));
}
```

The test above would produce such output:

```
[one, two][three, four]
[five, six][seven, eight]

===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 2, Passes: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```